# Image collision/intersection in JavaFX

Tags: java, image, javafx, collision-detection

I am trying to develop a game in javaFX where score will be updated and obstacle will be invisible when two images will intersect.But unfortunately,in the game score is updating continuously.
I think i can not make the image invisible properly in game.
[image: Problem]
Here's the full code of related class:

```
package minion.Model;

import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.application.Platform;

public class Minion extends Application implements Runnable{
    private Group root;
    private StackPane stackpane;
    private Scene mainbgscene;
    private ImageView mainbgv,heartIm1,heartIm2,heartIm3,characterIm,obsIm,obsIm2,obsIm3,obsIm4,obsIm5,obsIm6,obsIm7;
    private Image mainbg,heart1,character,obs,obs2,obs3,obs4,obs5,obs6,obs7;
    private VBox mainvbox,scoreVbox,characterVbox,obsVbox;
    private HBox heartHbox,scoreHbox;
    private Stage stageContainer;
    private Label scoreLabel;
    private Rectangle scoreBox;
    private Runnable r1;
    private int characterBoundary,life;
    private boolean flag1 =true;
    private double characterX,characterY;
    public static int score,lastScore;

    //For moving obstacle's start and end position
    private double obsStartX,obsStart2X,obsStart3X,obsStart4X,obsStart5X,obsStart6X,obsStart7X,obsEndX;
    public boolean gameRun;

    public Minion(){
        life = 4;
        characterX = 0.0;
        characterY = 450.0;
        obsStartX = 1100.0;
        obsStart2X = 1175.0;
        obsStart3X = 1150.0;
        obsStart4X = 800.0;
        obsStart5X = 1200.0;
        obsStart6X = 1000.0;
        obsStart7X = 700.0;
        obsEndX = -200.00;
        gameRun = true;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(gameRun){    
            obsStartX -= 1;
            obsStart2X -= 1;
            obsStart3X -= 1;
            obsStart4X -= 1;
            obsStart5X -= 1;
            obsStart6X -= 1;
            obsStart7X -= 1;
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                //Changing Position
                obsIm.setTranslateX(obsStartX);     
                obsIm2.setTranslateX(obsStart2X);
                obsIm3.setTranslateX(obsStart3X);
                obsIm4.setTranslateX(obsStart4X);
                obsIm5.setTranslateX(obsStart5X);
                obsIm6.setTranslateX(obsStart6X);
                obsIm7.setTranslateX(obsStart7X);
                updatePoint();
                //If a obstacle reach end screen then again it will start
                if(obsStartX == obsEndX){
                    obsStartX = (double)Range(2500,1400);
                    obsIm.setVisible(true);
                    obsIm.setImage(obstacleSelect());
                    obsIm.setTranslateY(Range(200,100));
                }
                if(obsStart2X == obsEndX){
                    obsStart2X = (double)Range(2200,1800);
                    obsIm2.setVisible(true);
                    obsIm2.setImage(obstacleSelect());
                    obsIm2.setTranslateY(Range(380,280));
                }
                if(obsStart3X == obsEndX){
                    obsStart3X = (double)Range(2700,1500);
                    obsIm3.setVisible(true);
                    obsIm3.setImage(obstacleSelect());
                    obsIm3.setTranslateY(Range(530,400));
                }
                if(obsStart4X == obsEndX){
                    obsStart4X = (double)Range(1900,1800);
                    obsIm4.setVisible(true);
                    obsIm4.setImage(obstacleSelect());
                    obsIm4.setTranslateY(Range(200,100));
                }
                if(obsStart5X == obsEndX){
                    obsStart5X = (double)Range(2000,1700);
                    obsIm5.setVisible(true);
                    obsIm5.setImage(obstacleSelect());
                    obsIm5.setTranslateY(Range(380,280));
                }
                if(obsStart6X == obsEndX){
                    obsStart6X = (double)Range(1700,1500);
                    obsIm6.setVisible(true);
                    obsIm6.setImage(obstacleSelect());
                    obsIm6.setTranslateY(Range(530,400));
                }
                if(obsStart7X == obsEndX){
                    obsStart7X = (double)Range(1900,1400);
                    obsIm7.setVisible(true);
                    obsIm7.setImage(obstacleSelect());
                    obsIm7.setTranslateY(Range(380,280));
                }
            });
            try{
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    }

    public void start(Stage stage){
        //score
        score = 0;
        scoreBox = new Rectangle(20,20,150,20);
        scoreHbox = new HBox();
        scoreHbox.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,1030));
        scoreBox.setFill(Color.rgb(218, 119, 255, 0.7));
        scoreHbox.getChildren().addAll(scoreBox);
        scoreLabel = new Label("Score: " + String.valueOf(score));
        scoreLabel.setTextFill(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 1.0));
        scoreVbox = new VBox();
        scoreVbox.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,1050));
        scoreVbox.getChildren().add(scoreLabel);

        stage.setTitle("Minion");
        root = new Group();
        stackpane = new StackPane();
        mainbgscene = new Scene(root,1200,650);

        //All types of Image loading
        mainbgv = new ImageView();
        mainbg = new Image("minion/image/level1.jpeg");
        mainbgv.setImage(mainbg);
        mainvbox = new VBox();
        mainvbox.getChildren().add(mainbgv);
        heart();
        character();
        obstacle();
        stackpane.getChildren().addAll(mainvbox,heartHbox,scoreHbox,scoreVbox,characterVbox,obsVbox);
        root.getChildren().add(stackpane);

        mainbgscene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,e->{
        if(flag1){
            flag1 = false;
            Thread t1 = new Thread(this);
            t1.start();
        }
        //Character Move in up
        /*if(e.getCode()==KeyCode.UP){
            Runnable r2 = new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                for(int i =0;i<30;++i){    
                    characterY -= 1;
                    characterIm.setTranslateY(characterY);
                    try{  

                    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Exception handled "+e);}
                }
                }
            };
            Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
            t2.start();
            t2.interrupt();
        }*/

        if(e.getCode()==KeyCode.UP){
            TranslateTransition translateTransUp =
            new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(600), characterIm);
            translateTransUp.setFromY(characterY);
            characterY -= 90.0;
            characterBoundary = characterBound(characterX,characterY);
            if(characterBoundary == 1){
                translateTransUp.setToY(characterY);
                translateTransUp.play();
            }
            else
                characterY += 90.0;
        }
        if(e.getCode()==KeyCode.RIGHT){
            TranslateTransition translateTransition =
            new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(600), characterIm);
            translateTransition.setFromX(characterX);
            characterX += 100.0;
            characterBoundary = characterBound(characterX,characterY);
            if(characterBoundary==1){
                translateTransition.setToX(characterX);
                translateTransition.play();
            }
            else
               characterX -= 100.0; 
        }
        if(e.getCode()==KeyCode.DOWN){
            TranslateTransition translateTransition =
            new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(600), characterIm);
            translateTransition.setFromY(characterY);
            characterY += 90.0;
            characterBoundary = characterBound(characterX,characterY);
            if(characterBoundary==1){
                translateTransition.setToY(characterY);
                translateTransition.play();
            }
            else
                characterY -= 90.0; 
        }
        if(e.getCode()==KeyCode.LEFT){
            TranslateTransition translateTransition =
            new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(600), characterIm);
            translateTransition.setFromX(characterX);
            characterX -= 100.0;
            characterBoundary = characterBound(characterX,characterY);
            if(characterBoundary==1){
                translateTransition.setToX(characterX);
                translateTransition.play();
            }
            else
               characterX += 100.0; 
        }

        });
        stageContainer = stage;
        stage.setScene(mainbgscene);
        stage.show();
    }

    //Character choose
    public void character(){
        characterIm = new ImageView();
        character = new Image("minion/image/minion.png");
        characterIm.setImage(character);
        characterIm.setTranslateX(characterX);
        characterIm.setTranslateY(characterY);
        characterVbox = new VBox();
        characterVbox.getChildren().add(characterIm);
    }
    //Select character Boundary
    public int characterBound(double characterX,double characterY){
        if(characterX <= 1100.0 && characterX >= 0.0 && characterY <= 450.0 && characterY >= 0.0)
            return 1;
        else 
            return 0;
    }

    //Random range
    public int Range(int max,int min){
        int range = Math.abs(max - min) + 1;     
        return (int)(Math.random() * range) + (min <= max ? min : max);
    }

    //Generating obstacle initially
    public void obstacle(){
        int a = Range(200,100);
        obsIm = new ImageView();
        obs = obstacleSelect();
        obsIm.setImage(obs);
        obsIm.setTranslateX(obsStartX);
        obsIm.setTranslateY(a);

        int b = Range(200,100);
        obsIm4 = new ImageView();
        obs4 = obstacleSelect();
        obsIm4.setImage(obs4);
        obsIm4.setTranslateX(obsStart4X);
        obsIm4.setTranslateY(a);

        int c = Range(380,280);
        obsIm2 = new ImageView();
        obs2 = obstacleSelect();
        obsIm2.setImage(obs2);
        obsIm2.setTranslateX(obsStart2X);
        obsIm2.setTranslateY(c);

        int d = Range(380,280);
        obsIm5 = new ImageView();
        obs5 = obstacleSelect();
        obsIm5.setImage(obs5);
        obsIm5.setTranslateX(obsStart5X);
        obsIm5.setTranslateY(d);

        int e = Range(380,280);
        obsIm7 = new ImageView();
        obs7 = obstacleSelect();
        obsIm7.setImage(obs7);
        obsIm7.setTranslateX(obsStart7X);
        obsIm7.setTranslateY(e);

        int f = Range(530,400);
        obsIm3 = new ImageView();
        obs3 = obstacleSelect();
        obsIm3.setImage(obs3);
        obsIm3.setTranslateX(obsStart3X);
        obsIm3.setTranslateY(f);

        int g = Range(530,400);
        obsIm6 = new ImageView();
        obs6 = obstacleSelect();
        obsIm6.setImage(obs6);
        obsIm6.setTranslateX(obsStart6X);
        obsIm6.setTranslateY(g);

        obsVbox = new VBox();
        obsVbox.getChildren().addAll(obsIm,obsIm2,obsIm3,obsIm4,obsIm5,obsIm6,obsIm7);
    }
    //Select obstacle Randomly
    public Image obstacleSelect(){
        String obsName;
        int choice = Range(0,6);//7 types of obstacle
        switch (choice) {
            case 0:
                obsName = "minion/image/obs1.png";
                break;
            case 1:
                obsName = "minion/image/obs2.png";
                break;
            case 2:
                obsName = "minion/image/obs3.png";
                break;
            case 3:
                obsName = "minion/image/obs4.png";
                break;
            case 4:
                obsName = "minion/image/obs5.png";
                break;
            case 5:
                obsName = "minion/image/obs6.png";
                break;
            default:
                obsName = "minion/image/obs7.png";
                break;
        }
        Image image = new Image(obsName);
        return image;
    }

    //Showing heart
     public void heart(){
        heart1 = new Image("minion/image/heart.png");

        heartIm1 = new ImageView();
        heartIm1.setImage(heart1);

        heartIm2 = new ImageView();
        heartIm2.setImage(heart1);

        heartIm3 = new ImageView();
        heartIm3.setImage(heart1);

        heartHbox = new HBox();
        heartHbox.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,0,15));
        heartHbox.getChildren().addAll(heartIm1,heartIm2,heartIm3);
    }
    public void updatePoint(){
        //obsStartX==characterX&&characterIm.getY()==obsIm.getY()
        if(obsIm.getBoundsInParent().intersects(characterIm.getBoundsInParent())){
            obsIm.setVisible(false);
            life -= 1;
            lifeUpdate();
            score+=10;
            Platform.runLater(()->{
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + String.valueOf(score));
            });
        }
        if(obsIm2.getBoundsInParent().intersects(characterIm.getBoundsInParent())){
            obsIm2.setVisible(false);
            life -= 1;
            lifeUpdate();
            Platform.runLater(()->{
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + String.valueOf(score));
            });
        }
        if(obsIm3.getBoundsInParent().intersects(characterIm.getBoundsInParent())){
            obsIm3.setVisible(false);
            score += 20;
            Platform.runLater(()->{
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + String.valueOf(score));
            });
        }
        if(obsIm4.getBoundsInParent().intersects(characterIm.getBoundsInParent())){
            obsIm4.setVisible(false);
            score += 30;
            Platform.runLater(()->{
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + String.valueOf(score));
            });
        }
        if(obsIm5.getBoundsInParent().intersects(characterIm.getBoundsInParent())){
            obsIm5.setVisible(false);
            score += 50;
            Platform.runLater(()->{
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + String.valueOf(score));
            });
        }
        if(obsIm6.getBoundsInParent().intersects(characterIm.getBoundsInParent())){
            obsIm6.setVisible(false);
            score += 40;
            Platform.runLater(()->{
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + String.valueOf(score));
            });
        }
        if(obsIm7.getBoundsInParent().intersects(characterIm.getBoundsInParent())){
            obsIm7.setVisible(false);
            score += 40;
            Platform.runLater(()->{
                scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + String.valueOf(score));
            });
        }
    }
    public void lifeUpdate(){
        switch (life) {
            case 3:
                heartIm3.setVisible(false);
                break;
            case 2:
                heartIm2.setVisible(false);
                break;
            case 1:
                heartIm1.setVisible(false);
                break;
            default:
                GameOver gameOver = new GameOver();
                gameRun = false;
                gameOver.start(stageContainer);
                break;
        }
    }

    public int getScore(){
        return score;
    }
}
```

It's my first project in java and i tried in many ways to solve this problem.But failed.It will be really helpful for me if you can solve this.
here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What's going wrong*

Just making something invisible will not remove it from the scene, it's still there, it's just that you can't see it, so the object is still bouncing around the scene running up your score.

*How to fix it*

You add all of the images to a vbox:

```
obsVbox.getChildren().addAll(obsIm,obsIm2,obsIm3,obsIm4,obsIm5,obsIm6,obsIm7);
```

Instead of making an image visible or invisible, add or remove it from the vbox.

```
obsVbox.getChildren().remove(<appropriate obsIm imageview reference>);
```

Obviously in your code replace  with the actual image you want to remove.

If it is not in the vbox, it won't be displayed.  Also once it is removed from the display, you don't need to keep processing it, so in your run method, you can loop through the items which are currently in obsVbox and only update them.  That would mean that you aren't trying to move around the items not in the vbox and they can't effect the player's score.

*Aside*

You might want to read up on [game loops in JavaFX](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops-fx.html) and use an AnimationTimer as recommended in that article.  Then you don't need to write multi-threaded code and use Platform.runLater as you have in your current code.  Also note that your current code is wrong, you should not modify attributes of objects in the active scene graph (such as visibility state) from outside the JavaFX application thread.

Also rather than different variables for different aspects of your game objects and eight different versions of them, just create a GameObject class with attributes like startX, imageView, etc and place them in a list which you loop through when you need to process it.  It will make your code much smaller and easier for you to maintain.

Comment: Based on your answer, i changed some code and logic.Now it's working.I can't express how valuable your answer is to me.Thanks sir....:D