# Beginner: Extend a class in javaFx

Tags: java, inheritance, javafx, javafx-8

I am developing a game in java.For my game i designed a level.Now i want to design another level for my game.It will be really helpful for my new level if i can extend my previous level.
In game i am doing stage change in various level.For that i have to extend Application class.As java do not support multiple inheritance, is there any other way to going different level without doing stage change?

**Stage Change:**

```
    //LevelOne selection
    levelOneIm = new ImageView();
    levelOne = new Image("minion/image/levelOne.jpeg");
    levelOneIm.setImage(levelOne);
    levelOneIm.setTranslateX(300);
    levelOneIm.setTranslateY(200);
    levelOneIm.setOnMouseClicked(e -> { 
        popUp.show();
        popUpOk.setOnAction(ab -> {
            try {
                userName = popUpUserName.getText();
            } catch(Exception a){
                System.out.println("Exception handled");
            }     
            //Going to Main Game and popup stage closing
            Minion minion = new Minion();
            popUp.close();
            minion.gameRun = true;
            minion.start(stage);//Level1 stage change
    });
    });

    //LevelTwo selection
    levelTwoIm = new ImageView();
    levelTwo = new Image("minion/image/levelTwo.jpg");
    levelTwoIm.setImage(levelTwo);
    levelTwoIm.setTranslateX(500);
    levelTwoIm.setTranslateY(200);
    levelTwoIm.setOnMouseClicked(e -> { 
        popUp.show();
        popUpOk.setOnAction(ab -> {
            try {
                userName = popUpUserName.getText();
            } catch(Exception a){
                System.out.println("Exception handled");
            }     
            //Going to LevelTwo and popup stage closing
            LevelTwo levelTwo= new LevelTwo();
            popUp.close();
            levelTwo.gameRun = true;
            levelTwo.start(stage);
    });
    });
```

**Level1:**

```
public class Minion extends Application implements Runnable{
    private Group root;
    private StackPane stackpane;
    private Scene mainbgscene;
    private ImageView mainbgv,heartIm1,heartIm2,heartIm3,characterIm,obsIm,obsIm2,obsIm3,obsIm4,obsIm5,obsIm6,obsIm7;
    private Image mainbg,heart1,character,obs,obs2,obs3,obs4,obs5,obs6,obs7;
    private VBox mainvbox,scoreVbox,characterVbox,obsVbox;
    private HBox heartHbox,scoreHbox;
    private Stage stageContainer;
    private Label scoreLabel;
    private Rectangle scoreBox;
```

**Level2:**

```
public class LevelTwo extends Application implements Runnable{
    private Group root;
    private StackPane stackpane;
    private Scene mainbgscene;
    private ImageView mainbgv,heartIm1,heartIm2,heartIm3,characterIm,obsIm,obsIm2,obsIm3,obsIm4,obsIm5,obsIm6,obsIm7;
    private Image mainbg,heart1,character,obs,obs2,obs3,obs4,obs5,obs6,obs7;
    private VBox mainvbox,scoreVbox,characterVbox,obsVbox;
    private HBox heartHbox,scoreHbox;
    private Stage stageContainer;
    private Label scoreLabel;
    private Rectangle scoreBox;
    private Runnable r1;
    private int characterBoundary,life;
    private boolean flag1 =true;
    private boolean obf1,obf2,obf3,obf4,obf5,obf6,obf7;
    private double characterX,characterY;
    public static int score,lastScore;
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your design.  Refactor your application to utilize the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  The application should not be responsible for implementing logic for a level, nor should it be implementing Runnable.  Your application class should be responsible only for implementing the JavaFX application lifecycle, as defined in the [JavaFX application javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html).  In fact, your application should be a really small class.

Instead, tasks such as implementing a game level should be delegated to other classes that handle those things. [Favoring composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059956/image-collision-intersection-in-javafx) can make it easier for you to associate different functional attribute with items rather than sticking to a strict and sometimes inflexible hierarchy, which can suffer from issues and restrictions such as the [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem).

For solution to problems which might seem like they are best suited for solving via multiple inheritance, you could try a [twin pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_pattern), which is really just a form of delegation as previously recommended in this post.

To understand how to go about refactoring your program, study up on object oriented design principles and techniques, such as [responsibility driven design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsibility-driven_design) and [crc modeling](http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/crcModel.htm), then validate that your design fits together on a run-time basis using some simple [sequence diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram).  As far a book recommendation for learning this stuff, perhaps pick up a copy of [Object Design: Roles, Responsibilities, and Collaborations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379430)